# Как удалить базу данных Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Как удалить базу данных Postgres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если пользователь базы - `www-data`, а база - `database`, то можно так:

```
$ sudo -u www-data dropdb database
```

[Подробнее](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.6/manage-ag-dropdb) об утилите `dropdb` и командe DROP DATABASE.

Answer (score 2):

Из клиента psql:

```
postgres=# drop database database_name;
```